# Django models ,Posgres db shell error ERROR: relation "trainingdata_trainingdata" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I have django app named TrainingData....
Training data modeels.py

```
class TrainingData(models.Model):

    UserName= models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    UserAge=models.TextField(default='')
    UserCitiesVisited=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    UserLocation=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    UserDescription=models.TextField(default='')
    UserActivity=models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    ActivityType=models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    ActivityDescription=models.TextField(default='')    


with open("/home/anish/ElisiyaActivitiesdata/activities/items.csv") as f:
    First_Name=""
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        Member_Name=row[0],
        Member_location=row[1],
        Member_age=row[2],
        Member_CitiesVisited=row[3]
        Member_Description=row[4]
        Activity=row[5]
        Activity_Type=row[6]
        Activity_desc=row[7]

        TD=TrainingData(UserName=First_Name,UserLocation=Member_location,UserAge=Member_age)
        TD.save()
```

I am able to run syncdb,run server sucess fully
even if i do \dt on postgres shell i see data added in my table

my question is why i am no able to access The Tables created by django framework?
when i do select queries from shell...
is it because of my ubuntu which might be not allowing the access to app even though iam using posgres as su..?

Comment: are you see `trainingdata_trainingdata` table in postgresql shell when you enter `\dt` command?

Comment: yes but i see as Trainingdata_trainingdata

Comment: so, what is the problem?

Comment: I am not able to access those tables when i am running select queries from   dbshell of Postgres...

Comment: only one  noo relation exists although i see a relation in db when i do \dt .I want to acess them from postgres shell